# MySQLi "bind_param" in cycle

Tags: php, mysqli

Why can I not use "bind_param" like this? Are there any alternative ways to use Binding in a cycle?

```
$insert = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$tableName.' ('.implode($colum, ', ').') VALUES ('.implode($placeholder, ', ').'); ');

for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) { 
    $insert->bind_param($query[$i]['type'], $query[$i]['value']); 
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem further. Do you get an error message? Did you try debugging your code by echoing the request string and the contents of `$query`?

Comment: I get this a error: "Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement".  Tnx for the answer:).

Comment: You could use `array_fill` to get exactly `$count` items in `$placeholder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your error makes it pretty clear: your `$placeholder` array doesn't contain the same number of placeholders as you have parameters in your `$query` array.

Check the code building the `$placeholder` and `$query` arrays. If you can't find the problem, add that piece of code in your question.

---

Ok, sorry, I'm not used to `mysqli`. Apparently you have to pass all the parameters in one call to `bind_param`. That's annoying, but there's a workaround.

The [`call_user_func_array`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) function allows you to pass the arguments to a function as an array.

So you can:

- construct the string of types by looping through the parameters;
- make an array `$params` with that string at index 0, and the parameters' values at subsequent indexes;
- call `call_user_func_array(array($insert, 'bind_param'), $params);`.

That would look like this:

```
$insert = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$tableName.' ('.implode($colum, ', ').') VALUES ('.implode($placeholder, ', ').'); ');

$values = array();
for ($i=0 ; $i<$count ; $i++) { 
    $types .= $query[$i]['type']; // this needs to be one single character from [idsb]
    $values[] = $query[$i]['value'];
}

$params = array_merge(array($types), $values);
call_user_func_array(array($insert, 'bind_param'), $params);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Query is constructed correct. The problem in the "param_bind" to fit all the placeholders in a single function call. I do not know how to do it. Do you have any ideas?